# Editing a static tableview that extends off the view

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode6

I currently have a static tableview that I'm editing in Xcode 6. The table will require that the user would have to scroll to see all of the contents off the table. I have reached the edge of the screen in Xcode and I can't seem to find a way to edit the content that extends off the screen. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select your view controller in the storyboard
2. Choose the size inspector on the right pane
3. View Controller > Simulated Size -> set to `Freeform`
4. Change the height value to be as large as you need

**OR**

1. Scroll while your cursor is over the tableview.

I recommend the first approach because it allows you and anyone else working on this storyboard file to quickly see the entire view at a glance without having to scroll every time.